# SAXParseException - noe4j:config - happens only on server deployment (Linux)

Tags: java, spring, xsd, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I have a project that uses neo4j. 
It is built and deployed successfully on my local Tomcat server (in Eclipse), but when deployed to Linux as a war and started, I get this error:

```
<pre>
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Failed to import bean definitions from URL location [classpath:applicationContext-algorithms.xml]
Offending resource: class path resource [applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Failed to import bean definitions from URL location [classpath:applicationContext-processed-dao.xml]
Offending resource: class path resource [applicationContext-algorithms.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Failed to import bean definitions from URL location [classpath:applicationContext-datasource.xml]
Offending resource: class path resource [applicationContext-processed-dao.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 21 in XML document from class path resource [applicationContext-datasource.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 21; columnNumber: 56; cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'neo4j:config'.
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.FailFastProblemReporter.error(FailFastProblemReporter.java:68)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:85)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:76)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.importBeanDefinitionResource(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:246)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseDefaultElement(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:197)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:182)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:139)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:108)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:493)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:390)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:174)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:209)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:180)
        at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:125)
        at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:94)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:130)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:451)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:389)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:294)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4939)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5434)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:983)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1660)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Failed to import bean definitions from URL location [classpath:applicationContext-processed-dao.xml]
Offending resource: class path resource [applicationContext-algorithms.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Failed to import bean definitions from URL location [classpath:applicationContext-datasource.xml]
Offending resource: class path resource [applicationContext-processed-dao.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 21 in XML document from class path resource [applicationContext-datasource.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 21; columnNumber: 56; cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'neo4j:config'.
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.FailFastProblemReporter.error(FailFastProblemReporter.java:68)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:85)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:76)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.importBeanDefinitionResource(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:246)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseDefaultElement(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:197)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:182)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:139)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:108)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:493)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:390)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:174)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:209)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.importBeanDefinitionResource(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:240)
        ... 33 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Failed to import bean definitions from URL location [classpath:applicationContext-datasource.xml]
Offending resource: class path resource [applicationContext-processed-dao.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 21 in XML document from class path resource [applicationContext-datasource.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 21; columnNumber: 56; cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'neo4j:config'.
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.FailFastProblemReporter.error(FailFastProblemReporter.java:68)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:85)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:76)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.importBeanDefinitionResource(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:246)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseDefaultElement(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:197)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:182)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:139)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:108)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:493)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:390)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:174)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:209)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.importBeanDefinitionResource(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:240)
        ... 44 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 21 in XML document from class path resource [applicationContext-datasource.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 21; columnNumber: 56; cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'neo4j:config'.
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:396)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:174)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:209)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.importBeanDefinitionResource(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:240)
        ... 55 more
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 21; columnNumber: 56; cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'neo4j:config'.
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator$XSIErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.reportSchemaError(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.handleStartElement(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.emptyElement(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.loadDocument(DefaultDocumentLoader.java:75)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:388)
        ... 60 more

Dec 02, 2013 12:21:01 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Dec 02, 2013 12:21:01 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStop
SEVERE: Exception sending context destroyed event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
java.lang.IllegalStateException: BeanFactory not initialized or already closed - call 'refresh' before accessing beans via the ApplicationContext
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.getBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:171)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.destroyBeans(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1090)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1064)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1010)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.closeWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:559)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextDestroyed(ContextLoaderListener.java:143)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:4980)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5626)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:232)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:160)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:983)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1660)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

</pre>
```

This is the relevant application context. I just would like to specify that it is imported by another applicationContext.xml file (it's a big project).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:neo4j="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/neo4j" 
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/neo4j http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/neo4j/spring-neo4j-2.2.xsd‏
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd">

    <context:spring-configured/>
    <context:annotation-config />

    <neo4j:config storeDirectory="/export/data/graph.db"/>

    <neo4j:repositories base-package="com.vo.insight.processed" />



    <!-- MongoDB - for raw data -->

    <bean id="mongoRepository" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
        <constructor-arg name="mongo" ref="mongoDbServer" />
        <constructor-arg name="databaseName" value="${db.mongo.name}" />
        <!-- constructor-arg name="userCredentials" ref="mongoUserCradentials" /-->
    </bean>

    <bean id="mongoUserCradentials" class="org.springframework.data.authentication.UserCredentials">
        <constructor-arg name="username" value="${db.mongo.username}" />
        <constructor-arg name="password" value="${db.mongo.password}" />
    </bean>


    <!-- Factory bean that creates the Mongo instance -->
    <bean id="mongoDbServer" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoFactoryBean">
        <property name="host" value="${db.server.name}" />
        <property name="port" value="${db.mongo.port}" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Activate annotation configured components -->
    <context:annotation-config />

    <!-- Scan components for annotations within the configured package -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.vo.insight.rawdata.entity">
        <context:exclude-filter type="annotation"
            expression="org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration" />
    </context:component-scan>

    <tx:annotation-driven />

</beans>
```

I read in forums that it might has to do with mismatch versions so I went over all the xsd's to make sure that Spring and Neo4j versions match the XSD version. I also checked that the referenced xsd (spring-neo4j-2.2.xsd‏) exists in one of the WAR's jars.

If relevant, I use Maven, Spring 3.2.4.RELEASE and spring-data-neo4j-rest 2.3.1.RELEASE. Note: I know that my current implementation uses storeDirectory and not REST database but this only because I didn't succeed to integrate this yet. I don't think this is relevant to my issue because Maven imports the relevant packages using the latest dependency.

Again, in my local env. everything works great, it only fails on Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a enconding problem in your xml file. Probably you have some garbage character in your
`xsi:schemaLocation` definition:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:neo4j="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/neo4j" 
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/neo4j
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/neo4j/spring-neo4j-2.2.xsd‏
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd">
```

Just trying to copy and paste the neo4j xsd url in a browser urlbar is enough to see the problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot!  This solved the problem! Indeed, there was a question mark at the end of the URL which was not displayed in the Eclipse editor. Once I copied it to a Notepad, I could see it.